# How to control `warnings` for imported modules?

Tags: python, warnings, python-3.7

In Python 3.7, I'm using the `warnings` module with the warning filter set to `'always'`. This is not, however, reflected in a submodule I'm importing.

Is there a way to control the warning level across all imported modules or for each individually?